# iOS App: Swapping rootviewcontroller after performing login using swift has significant delay

Tags: ios, swift, swap, rootview

Hi I am using following function to swap from current root view controller to a new root view controller after saving the users "username" in an internal database. Although the code works and I can make a switch but it take very long to transition. sometime as much as 15s.

```
    func switchRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    if animated {
        UIView.transitionWithView(self.window!, duration: 0.5, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            let oldState: Bool = UIView.areAnimationsEnabled()
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
            self.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(oldState)
            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> () in
                if (completion != nil) {
                    completion!()
                }
        })
    } else {
        self.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
    }
}
```

This is how I am calling the function:

```
   api.postMulti(apiKey, contentType: "application/json", payLoad: payLoad, urlString: urlString, parameter: parameter){ (succeeded: Int, msg: String) -> () in

        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Failed", message: msg, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Okay")

        if succeeded == 422 {
            alert.title = "Failed"
            alert.message = "Username is already in use. Please selecet another one!"
        }

        else if succeeded == 500{
            alert.title = "Failed"
            alert.message = "Internal Server Error. Unable to process Request!"
        }

        else if succeeded == 200{
            //save to internal DataBase table: User
            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)

            let users = User(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

            users.username = self.userName.text

            var error: NSError?

            self.managedObjectContext?.save(&error)

            if let err = error {
                println(err.localizedFailureReason)
            } else {

                self.userName.text = ""
                alert.title = "Success"
                alert.message = "Loading App..."



                let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                var secondViewController: EveryTimeRun = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("everytime") as! EveryTimeRun

                self.switchRootViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)




                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


            }
        }

        // Move to the UI thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            // Show the alert
            alert.show()
        })
    }
```

Is there a mistake I am making.

**UPDATE:**

I am posting my POST function. It could be taking long:

```
        func postMulti(apikey: String, contentType: String, payLoad: Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>>, urlString: String, parameter: String, postCompleted : (succeeded: Int, msg: String) -> ()){

    let joinedUrl = urlString + parameter
    let url = NSURL(string: joinedUrl)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue(apikey, forHTTPHeaderField: "apikey")
    var error: NSError?


    let payLoadJSON = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(payLoad, options: nil, error: &error)
    request.HTTPBody = payLoadJSON

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)


        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary
        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if(err != nil) {
            //            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            postCompleted(succeeded: 0, msg: "Portal is not reachable. Please try again later")
        }
        else {
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                if let statusCode = parseJSON["statusCode"] as? Int {

                    postCompleted(succeeded: statusCode, msg: "")
                }
            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                postCompleted(succeeded: 1, msg: "Portal is not reachable. Please try again later")
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: so you're saying 'postMulti' takes as much as 15 seconds to run?

Comment: i dont think its 'postMulti' that takes that long. I believe its loading the root view controller that take time because 'success' 'loading app' is printed immediately after hitting the login button. Also if I replace the present viewcontroller with a new one its fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most expensive in time is this line:

```
self.managedObjectContext?.save(&error)
```

So sou should save in background or save after switching in viedDidAppear on `secondViewController`

With [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) there are useful method `saveWithBlock: completion:`

**Update:**

To animate view you can use this method:

```
var overlaywindow: UIWindow!
//

var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if let popupVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("everytime") as? EveryTimeRun
    {
        var frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        overlayWindow = UIWindow(frame: frame)

        popupVC.overlayWindow = overlayWindow
        overlayWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert
        overlayWindow.rootViewController = popupVC

        overlayWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        overlayWindow.alpha = 0

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations:
        {
            self.overlayWindow.alpha = 1
        })
    }
```

Comment: but if I use the following in the else block then it is fast: self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: whit this i get an error : everytimerun does not have a member named overlaywindow

Comment: Add it: "var overlaywindow: UIWindow!" in EveryTimeRun class

Comment: thanks. i also added "var addPostVC: FirstTimeRun = FirstTimeRun()" to EveryTimeRun. Still have same amount of latency. I guess its my post function. i have updated my question

Comment: when you call your POST function?

Comment: following calls the post: api.postMulti(apiKey, contentType: "application/json", payLoad: payLoad, urlString: urlString, parameter: parameter){ (succeeded: Int, msg: String) -> () in

Comment: if you run post in viewDidLoad, try to run it in viedDidAppear

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue indirectly. After tracing the code, I realised that following components were causing the delay:

1. POST method that was calling a rest API - Network Latency
2. Saving username to CoreData - Write Latency
3. Unloading the existing (ID: FirstTimeRun) viewcontroller - Unload Latency
4. Loading a new tabbedbar(ID: EveryTimeRun) viewcontroller - Load Latency

Of which 3 and 4 were the highest.

So in order to solve this problem, I did some research online and figured the best practice is to load the EveryTimeRun view controller and then load the FirstTimeRun modally on top of that if the user is not already logged in. Then dismiss the FirstTimeRun after successful login.

I guess this is a better way to achieve what I was trying to do. Loading and unloading viewcontrollers seamed like a bit of a hack.